# Find the highest or the lowest price based on the number of previous candles - Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking for the highest or lowest price based on the previous number of candles (14 candles) and work out the stop loss price from entry to highest high for long orders or lowest price for short orders.
But when included in the chart, the SL and TP are not correct (link is attached).

[image: Illustrations]

My script:

```
//The price of the highest high or the lowest low is based on the previous 14 candles

highest = ta.highest (high, 14) 

lowest = ta.lowest(low, 14)

//Calculate the price range from the closing price to the highest high or lowest low to make a stop loss

stoplossLong = highest - close

stoplossShort = close - lowest

// TP & SL for Long & Short

longstoppercent = float(strategy.position_avg_price - stoplossLong)

longtakeprofitpercentTP1 = float(strategy.position_avg_price + stoplossLong*1.5)

longtakeprofitpercentTP2 = float(strategy.position_avg_price + stoplossLong*3)

shortstoppercent = float(strategy.position_avg_price + stoplossShort)

shorttakeprofitpercentTP1 = float(strategy.position_avg_price - stoplossShort*1.5)

shorttakeprofitpercentTP2 = float(strategy.position_avg_price - stoplossShort*3)
```

Comment: You can improve readability of your Question by formatting the Code parts differently than the Q text using triple backticks like ```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is not to find the highest and lowest of 14 bars past. I'd recommend checking this by plotting highest and lowest.

I think that your problem lies in your calculations or in the strategy tester part.

```
var float long_sl_dist = 0.0
var float short_sl_dist = 0.0
var float long_tp1 = 0.0
var float long_tp2 = 0.0
var float short_tp1 = 0.0
var float short_tp2 = 0.0

// highest high and lowest low.
highest = ta.highest (high, 14)
lowest = ta.lowest(low, 14)

if condition //sample condition, for the showcase image
    // distance of higest/lowest to close (entry).
    long_sl_dist := math.abs(highest - close)
    short_sl_dist := math.abs(close - lowest)
    
    // stop loss and take profit.
    long_tp1 := close + (long_sl_dist*1.5)
    long_tp2 := close + (long_sl_dist*3.0)
    
    short_tp1 := close - (short_sl_dist*1.5)
    short_tp2 := close - (short_sl_dist*3.0)
```

SHowcase : [image]

Making the differences absolute (`math.abs()`) is something I usually do, because in some markets there can be a bug, where the difference can be negative, which is bad

I didn't really understand, why you used the `strategy.position_avg_price` variable, because that is something you need somewhere else than stop loss / take profit.

I used `close` as your entry.

Code Description:

- Variable Declaration in the beginning
- Defining highest/lowest
- When Condition is true, set (`:=`) variables
- close is the entry and the rest is self-explanatory

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have re-edited the script according to your support but it still doesn't seem to work the way I want. I think it's because it's not the correct information when entering the order (the part I wrote myself) or something. Can you help me check my entire script by following the attached link below. Very grateful
[My script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUb_i1pf3QYnZFG1JAvSUbd49E9Crr9t/view?usp=sharing)
[Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tDFGqzGNWpfS4SVbHvXtz0AndsYFKZZ7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [My script updated](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yd6ifybHGWkxePhAOtwOhLeYvp5ddgof/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: May you please send a fixed version of your code? This code seems bugged (Double parts).

Comment: [My script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WbwKF2-9oSgsLRwDoh2fdc01ViXnxP-a/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have updated it (link above), there are some mistakes in cutting and pasting, my mistake, please check again for me.